# How to open web project in iOS webview with domain other than localhost

Tags: ios, nginx, ssl, webview, ios-simulator

I have a project that runs on a domain like `https://nomatter.local.something.ru`. I want to open it in local webview in XCode with simulator. I also have installed certificates for the next url `https://nomatter.companyname.something.ru`

And when I try to open this `https://nomatter.companyname.something.ru` then webview is working, but when I try to open `https://nomatter.local.something.ru` it is not working.

My local project work like that: nginx in docker -> node.js bff with ssr -> js in browser

I'am trying to generate self-signed certificates and import it in simulator. It doesn't work.